# C# - Count how many times a button is clicked and show it in ListView on a different form

Tags: c#, listview, button, count

I have two forms, form1 and form2.

form1 has 3 buttons, button1(vanilla), button2(chocolate) and button3(nextpage)

form2 has a listView1

When the user clicks on the vanilla 3 times and chocolate 1 time,I want to to display "3" and "1" in the quantity column in the listView1 on form2.

there is a screenshot below.

**form1**

```
public partial class form1 : Form
{
private string vanilla = "Vanilla";
private string chocolate= "Chocolate";
private List<string> _values= new List<string>();
public form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!_values.Contains(vanilla))
   {
      _values.Add(vanilla);
   }           
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!_values.Contains(chocolate))
   {
      _values.Add(chocolate);
   } 
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2 form2 = new form2(_values);
    form2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
}
```

**form2**

```
public partial class form2 : Form
{                   
public form2(List<string> passedValues)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    foreach(var item in passedValues)
    {
       listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
}
```

[image]

**It should show 3 in vanilla row and 1 in chocolate row**

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the amount of times each flavour was selected.  Your list only holds the name of the flavour that was clicked.

If you had a `Dictionary<string, int>` then each time that flavour was selected, check if the key (flavour name) exists in the dictionary, if it does, increment the value.  If it's not in there create a new entry with value of 1.

Then when you create Form2 - loop through each KeyValuePair in the Dictionary, add the key to the flavour column and the value to the Quantity column.